# How to load new view when TTTabItem clicked

Tags: iphone, view, three20

Hi all
I am trying to set up a view that lets the user scroll a TTTabStrip. This TTTabStrip contains several TTTabItems. Does anyone know how I can define the action, when an item is clicked? I would like to load a new view controller into the view below the TTTabStrip.

Thanks, best regards, Doonot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every Cell in a TTTableView has a url property which you can set.

Then using TTNavigator you define to which view Controller does this url maps to.

Comment: That means it is only possible with the url mapping?

Comment: No, there's an action method as well called didSelectObject:atIndexPath: , look for it here : http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_table_view_controller.php

Comment: Ok. But why are you talking about TTTableView?